# Send array (object) with a POST jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

```
var data = {
    'ids': $("input[name='ids\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}),
    'price': $("input[name='price\\[\\]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();})
};

alert(data);


$.post("api/update_prices.php", {'data[]': data}, function (responseText) {
    alert(responseText);
});
```

or...

```
$.post("api/update_prices.php", data, function (responseText) {
    alert(responseText);
});
```

The alert data is outputting a Object (object). I was looking a Stackoverflow and it's still not working. alert(responseText) is never called.

Comment: Your second snippet should work. Isolate the code and try to find the problem. If you are on safari/chrome/firefox use console.log() to inspect objects with help of the javascript console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try specifying the content type as `"application/json"` in the jQuery Ajax API and then calling

> JSON.stringify(data);

also, open the web developer console in Google Chrome browser and navigate to the Network tab to see what is happening during the Ajax call. i.e. what data is sent and what data is received in the Ajax Call.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `serialize`? It sums up all the form data. It seems to be what you're trying to do with the `data` object.

```
$.post("api/update_prices.php", $(':input').serialize(), function (responseText) {
    alert(responseText);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

Your $.post function should be like this:

```
$.post("api/update_prices.php", {'data[]': JSON.stringify(data)}, function (responseText)  {
    alert(responseText);
});
```

Pay attention to **JSON.stringify**.